# Linux touch creating new unwanted files

Tags: linux, touch

I have a windows server sharing a folder for several Linux clients. Those Linux clients all use "touch" every minute on a file in the Windows shared folder.

I used to have a single "keepalive" file in the Windows server folder. Now, I have a bunch of those file, with some weird extensions.

[image]

Where do they come from ? What triggers those files ?

Comment: Do you know what switches, etc. and syntax the clients are using when they do this keepalive operation every minute? Please provide that in your answer if you know and can confirm.

Comment: There are no switches. A simple touch running from a crontab.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't another process hitting this share doing something like SED perhaps? It may be worth a double or triple check. I've seen something similiar with SED processes before but never with TOUCH in a Windows environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer. It came from the **rsync** command. While transferring a file, rsync creates an hidden file (starting with ".") and adds a suffix after the filename.

Those files never finished transferring correctly, so they remained in the folder. I have several clients rsyncing and touching on that file asynchronously, so that most likely triggered problems.

See this answer for more explanation : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted